# Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description -- FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, concatenation

I am trying to concat 3 videos and give effetcs using FFMPEG. My below script is giving error.
I am not able to understand what is the issue. Which index i am missing.

Script below:

```
    ffmpeg -i D:\ffmpeg_output\2021\04\14\Episode10_2952.mp4 
-i D:\ffmpeg_output\2021\04\14\Episode10_3507.mp4 
-i D:\ffmpeg_output\2021\04\14\Episode10_RmvAdVi_1_9226-2.mp4  
-filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=8.07[V01]; 
[V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=16.81[V02]; 
[V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=26.65,format=yuv420p[video]; 
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01]; [A01]
[2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02]; [A02]
[3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" 
-movflags +faststart D:\ffmpeg_output\2021\04\14\out_count_3_videos_1.mp4
```

I am getting following error:

Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=8.07[V01]; [V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=16.81[V02]; [V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=26.65,format=yuv420p[video]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01]; [A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02]; [A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri:c2=tri[audio].

Please advise the issue.

Kind Regards,

Comment: ffmpeg indexes inputs starting with 0, so `[3]` refers to the 4th input but your command has only 3 inputs.

Comment: Many Many thanks. I am not finding to button to accept the solution. Please guide.

Comment: Please help me to accept the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg indexes inputs starting with 0, so [3] refers to the 4th input but your command has only 3 inputs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1056422)

Comment: What a joke. The OP has already indicated in comments it has answered their Q.

Comment: Yes, it was answered. I was using extra index. Thanks for helping.